# Can't get JSON file into variable

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to parse the content of the JSON file into a variable called `weatherArray`. However, this variable is always an empty array.

```js
let weatherArray = [];

function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        weatherArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lon=55&lat=12", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

/* Expecting the value to be stored and be shown in console*/
console.log(weatherArray);
```

Comment: have you console.logged `responseText` to validate the server is sending something back?

Comment: How do you know it’s emprty? Where are you testing that? Outside the callback?

Comment: Do you know if the if statement is hit and have you checked the actual content of the response text? Try checking with something like fiddler what is happening between your request and your browser.

Comment: @Mark_M - yes, you picked it. The OP has console.log() an initialized empty array.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yep, console.logging `responseText` returns data from the json file.

Comment: @JoãoAraújo - As Mark_M pointed out, your `console.log()` statement executes prior to `weatherArray` being populated. The XHR is asynchronous so you have to manipulate and/or log the expected data in the handler.

Comment: @RandyCasburn so it means that I cannot have the variable with the new content outside of the function?

Comment: You can have it outside the function, but you can only get the data once the function is reached.

Comment: You can, but the idea is to collect the data in the function, and then pass it along to another function that will then operate on the data. The is the nature of JavaScript's asynchronous processing model. Study up on it, it is a foundation for JS.

Comment: @RacilHilan I'm now looking into Synchronous and Asynchronous in JavaScript to better understand this. Still, if I console.log(weatherArray) after calling the function in your new version, the variable doesn't contain the JSON array.

Comment: Yes, it does. Click on the [Run code snippet] button below my answer and you will see the JSON array printed out.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you! It's starting to make sense for me now.

Comment: Yes, you will find it pretty easy once you understand it. You make a call to the API, it takes time (milliseconds), the function gets invoked once the response arrives, only then you will have data to play with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're checking the results before they come back. You need to move the line:

```
console.log(weatherArray);
```

To inside the `onreadystatechange` function, which will check the results once they arrive. Also you need to call the `loadDoc()` function (you probably did that).

```js
let weatherArray = [];

function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        weatherArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(weatherArray);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lon=55&lat=12", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
loadDoc();
```

**EDIT** If you like to process the results in another function instead of inside `onreadystatechange`, you can call that function from `onreadystatechange`. You can do that with your global `weatherArray`, but I just recommend in this case to simply pass the data in a parameter:

```js
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      showWeather(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lon=55&lat=12", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function showWeather(weatherArray) {
  console.log(weatherArray);
}

loadDoc();
```

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is asynchronous call, and you are printing data before invoking the ajax call,

I made some changes try it.

```js
let weatherArray = [];

function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        weatherArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lon=55&lat=12", true);
    xhttp.send();
    
}
loadDoc();
/* Expecting the value to be stored and be shown in console*/
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to provide an alternative modern approach using the Fetch api and Promises.

1. First fetch from the api
2. Convert it to json
3. Return the promise
4. Listen for the promise and log the result in the callback

```js
function loadDoc() {
  return fetch("https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lon=55&lat=12")
    .then(res => res.json())

}

loadDoc().then((weatherArray) => {
  console.log(weatherArray);
})
```

Comment: thank you! what are the pros & cons of this alternative?

Comment: A con is that without polyfills [IE11 won't be supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch). Major pros are readability and developer experience.

Comment: It's not only IE (all versions including mobile), it will also not work in BlackBery, Opera Mini, an more importantly in Safari iOS before 8 and Safari Mac before 7.1 and Android before 4.4.4. However, the total users of those platforms is less than 10% globally (in can be higher in some countries).